# Chrome mistakenly applies locale to values inside CSSStyleSheet

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Is it a bug in Chrome `Version 65.0.3325.146` on macOS High Sierra that CSSStyleSheet applies locale to its values? The following html reproduces the error. It prints incorrect output for Russian system locale, where "," is used as decimal separator.

```
<script>
var el = document.createElement('style');
el.innerHTML = '.someclass {font-size: 3.5rem; line-height: 1.5rem;}';
document.head.appendChild(el);
console.log(el.sheet.cssRules[0].style.cssText);    
</script>
```

The output is:

```
font-size: 3,5rem; line-height: 1,5rem;
```

Expected output:

```
font-size: 3.5rem; line-height: 1.5rem;
```

Screenshot with problem (checked in browser console):

[image: Screenshot with problem]

Comment: How about the rule itself, does it work?

Comment: The rule itself works but I used the code to parse rules and reuse them later. Now it's broken.

Comment: This is fascinating. Is it a known bug? Are we sure it doesn't happen in other browsers?

Comment: @JeremyBanks don't think so, haven't found any information on it. Also it was happening right after update from Google Chrome 63 -> 64 -> 65 (both updates on the same day) and was resolved by itself as I described in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really strange things here.

Problem gone after commenting out the following strings from `~/.profile` and restarting Chrome:

```
export LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
export LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
export LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=
```

But after I uncommented the strings back - problem is not happening anymore. Tried Chrome & system restarts.

Chrome restarts did not help to solve the problem before commenting out the strings. Probably just system restart could solve the problem (haven't tried that) :)

**UPD**: Finally found, how to reproduce the problem - have to start Chrome from Terminal (command line) with these variable set (LC_NUMERIC, ...).